# Capturing with regex php

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

im stuck with the following regex..

```
(genre|style).*?(\.|\:|\||\>|\[|\-)
```

Im trying to capture all the genres in the following example and not the crap after.. I can get a couple but not all of them. Can you please explain to me how to capture all?  For example the line GENRE:........Hip-Hop is giving me trouble. Its also capturing PLAYTIME.. how can i stop capturing if multiple spaces are found?

```
GENRE       : Pop cult speech
genre......: Thrash Metal   crap1  crap2   
genre    : House
style: dance
genre.....:        house
genre 0djdjd f : House
style | elektronic house
genre > Metal Hard rock
GENRE:........Hip-Hop              PLAYTiME:....73:31          
Genre.....  - Indie                    Year   - 2019               
STYLE: Folk
GENRE........[ Euro-House   crap crap crap
Genre       : Hard Rock                     crap crap
```

Comment: Why do you have `(genre|style)` are you looking for lines that start with either of these ?

Comment: You have no clear delineation between what you want and the _JUNK_ afterwards. You have to decide a distinct delimiter. If you can't do that, then it can't be separated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture all the genre/style from your given text,

```
(?:genre|style)(?:\s+\w*)*[ :.|>[-]+\K[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ -][a-zA-Z]+)*
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?:genre|style)` - Matches either `genre` or `style` literally
- `(?:\s+\w*)*` - Matches optional text and this is only for sample `genre 0djdjd f : House` else this part was not needed indeed
- `[ :.|>[-]+` - Matches one or more these characters which appear before the genre/style text
- `\K` - Resets whatever matched so far
- `[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ -][a-zA-Z]+)*` - Matches alphabetical genre text which can be a single space or hyphen separated text.

**[Check this online demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sr8izW/1)**

Let me know if this captures precisely what you wanted.

Comment: This is working fine!! Thank you for the explanation! I would never got that for sure..

Comment: @user1997874: Glad to help. Also please consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem.